# Quartz Dependency Injection and Constructor

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

I'm trying to use DependencyInjection on Quartz.Job. My Job Class looks like this. Without constructor it works as expected. But when i add it is even not hitting the job. I added to my program.cs
`builder.Services.AddQuartz(x => x.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory());` part but still the same.

```
public class TestOperationsJob : IJob
{
    private readonly ITnLog tnLog;
    public TestOperationsJob(ITnLog tnLog)
    {
        this.tnLog = tnLog;
    }
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            string tnLogging = "Test";
            tnLog.AddLog(tnLogging, PriorityType.Informational);
            JobDataMap dataMap = context.Trigger.JobDataMap;
            string? value = dataMap.GetString("testValue");
            Console.WriteLine(value);
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string s = ex.Message;
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, my SchedulerClass is also looking like this.

```
public static async Task<IScheduler> Create(bool start = true)
    {
        var properties = new NameValueCollection
        {
            // -- History -- //
            ["quartz.plugin.recentHistory.storeType"] = "Quartz.Plugins.RecentHistory.Impl.InProcExecutionHistoryStore, Quartz.Plugins.RecentHistory",
            ["quartz.plugin.recentHistory.type"] = "Quartz.Plugins.RecentHistory.ExecutionHistoryPlugin, Quartz.Plugins.RecentHistory",

        };
        var sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
        var scheduler = await sf.GetScheduler();
        {
            var job = JobBuilder.Create<TestOperationsJob>()
                .WithIdentity("Test", "Test Job Group")
                .StoreDurably(true)
                .RequestRecovery(true)
                .Build();
            if (!scheduler.CheckExists(job.Key).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
            {
                await scheduler.AddJob(job, false);
            }

            var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                            .WithIdentity("TestOperations2")
                            .ForJob(job.Key)
                            .UsingJobData("testValue", "TestingValue")
                            //.StartAt()
                            .StartNow()
                            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(30).RepeatForever())
                            .Build();
            if (!scheduler.CheckExists(trigger.Key).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
            {
               await scheduler.ScheduleJob(trigger);
            }


        }
        if (start)
            await scheduler.Start();

        return scheduler;
    }
```

What should i do? I guees i need to add something with IJobFactory but i cant handle it

Comment: If you build your scheduler manually like that it surely won't have any dependency injection. Have your read [the documentation](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/microsoft-di-integration.html) and checked the [examples](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/tree/main/src)?